# IPV4 somente com PHP com link ipv4/ipv6

Tags: php, ip, ipv6

Eu sempre usei `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` para obter o **IP** do usuário/visitante em alguns sistemas.

Porém comecei a usar um IP FIXO no trabalho, que é **IPV4**, mas quando vou ver o registro eu acessei com **IPV6**.

Mas em sites como fóruns e blogs os sistemas em PHP deles registram o **IPV4**, e analisei os códigos e mesmo assim não consegui entender o algoritmo que consegue passar o **IPV6** ou outro método para **IPV4**.

Então acredito que seja possível somente com PHP, se alguém puder me ajudar.

Edição:
Eu instalei o SMF2 que estou acostumado em uma hospedagem gratuita (fora da minha rede) e testei, ele ao invés de registrar o IPV4 registrou o IPV6 mesmo, isso está me deixando um tanto confundo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Por que em outros sites pessoais que usam o mesmo sistema mostram o meu IPV4.

Comment: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8305

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu consegui descobrir a razão de alguns sites pegarem o IPV4 mesmo usando IPV6 ao mesmo tempo e a minha hospedagem não, as rotas usadas podem variar do servidor onde foi hospedado a script PHP, então não tem realmente como isso ser feito sem uso de serviço de terceiros.

Agora uma solução alternativa, vale lembrar que não vou postar o serviço de terceiros que usei por que acredito que isso seja mal visto pela comunidade, e que também pode ser considerado um sistema mal feito.

Para poder solucionar eu usei este serviço para converter em JSON o IPV4:

```
http://<ipv4 ipv6 service>/json/widgetdata.php?callback=_jqjsp&_1518034744039=
```

Ele retorna uma JSON:

```
_jqjsp({"address":"179.XXX.XXX.XX5","proto":"ipv4","country_code":"BR","country":"Brazil"})
```

Mas não se pode usar xmlHTTPrequest para receber valores de outra um JSON de outra hospedagem, então através da URL dela eu alterei o termo da variavel **callback** de maneira que a gambiarra fazendo com que o PHP do serviço criasse uma variavel Javascript usando o sinal de igual (=) assim %3D para URL aceitar:

```
http://<ipv4 ipv6 service>/json/widgetdata.php?callback=dataipv4%3D
```

E chamando ele por HTML a variavel fica acessivel ao seu navegador como um objeto JSON:

```
var dataipv4=({"address":"177.XXX.XXX.XX5","proto":"ipv4","country_code":"BR","country":"Brazil"})
```

Então agora sim com xmlHTTPRequest bastou usar a variavel dataipv4.address para obter o IP e enviar por método GET pra um PHP que use o IP:

```
function showIpv(ip) {
     var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
     xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
         if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            console.log()
         }
     };
     xmlhttp.open("GET", "write_ipv4.php?ip="+ip, true);
     xmlhttp.send();
}
```

O arquivo write_ipv4.php que fica na hospedagem:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['ip']) && !empty($_GET['ip'])){
   /* User a variavel global $_GET['ip'] da maneira que preferir 
      Por exemplo:
      echo $_GET['ip']
      retorna o IP no formato XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
   */
}else{
   console.log('Acesso direto proibido');
}
?>
```